# Jinja Template variable displays as label but not as attribute in Flask app

Tags: html, jinja2

I cannot for the life of me figure out why the `value` attribute returns `'{{ edit_card}}'`

while `'>{{edit_card.id}}</input>'` returns the actual value of the template variable.

`<input type="hidden" id="filex" name="filex" value="{{ edit_card.id }}" style="display: none;">{{edit_card.id}}</input>`

[image: This is what I am talking about]

Thanks:

Comment: Which browser are you using? I just copied and pasted what you have and it gave ```1``` for both places. Tried this in both Firefox and Brave. It's possible you have a typo or could be your version of Jinja (mine is 3.0.1)

Comment: I am using the latest versions of Chrome, Edge, and Firefox, I have tried all three browsers and have also used them in private mode as well, nothing works, I am using the following repository as a base:  https://github.com/FloatingOctothorpe/python-kanban/. Would you know how to pass  ```>{{edit_card.id}}</input>``` to the Flask backend?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the question you asked - the one about passing something to the backend?

Comment: well, I was just wondering if it was possible to pass the label portion of this line:                    ```<input type="hidden" id="filex" name="filex" value="{{ edit_card.id }}" style="display: none;">{{edit_card.id}}</input``` such as ```{{edit_card.id}}</input>``` can be pass to the Flask backend via post request

Comment: If you submit a form, the form will submit the names of the fields and their values. Outside of this, you'll have to use Javascript to send other data to your backend